# Dialog pop up doesn't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog box that adds an item to a dropdownlist;
here's the code.

```
$(function () {
    $('#applicantDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Add Applicant',
        buttons: {
            'Save': function () {
                var createApplicantForm = $('#createApplicantForm');
                if (createApplicantForm.valid()) {
                    $.post(createApplicantForm.attr('action'), createApplicantForm.serialize(), function (data) {
                        if (data.Error != '') {
                            alert(data.Error);
                        }
                        else {
                            // Add the new Applicant to the dropdown list and select it
                            $('#Applicant').append(
                                    $('<option></option>')
                                        .val(data.id_applicant)
                                        .html(data.Applicant.Applicant_name)
                                        .prop('selected', true)  // Selects the new Applicant in the DropDown LB
                                );
                            $('#applicantDialog').dialog('close');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#applicantAddLink').click(function () {
        var createFormUrl = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#applicantDialog').html('')
        .load(createFormUrl, function () {
            // The createGenreForm is loaded on the fly using jQuery load. 
            // In order to have client validation working it is necessary to tell the 
            // jQuery.validator to parse the newly added content
            jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#createApplicantForm');
            $('#applicantDialog').dialog('open');
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

My problem is that when the form is saved and the item is added, it never closes the dialog box. When I click on cancel, the list is not updated until I refresh the page.
Is it a problem with postback and how can I deal with that?
Thanks

Comment: Any errors in console? It looks like that there is an error in `$('#Applicant').append(...);` Maybe `data.Applicant` is undefined? Check if the `data` variable is fine.

Comment: you are right there was a problem with data I forget to add.Applicant but till now it doesn't work !!!

Comment: I tried to delete the$('#Applicant').append but still doesn't work 
any suggestions

Comment: I made another test I omitted all the code in the else section and change it with an alert('test') and seems he didn't enter in the else section it's not normal!!!

Comment: Put `console.log(data);` or `alert(data);` at the begining of the callback and tell us what you get. Perhaps `data` is undefined and it crashes when trying to evaluate `data.Error`. And more important: open the console and tell us what errors are there!

Comment: here is what I get                                                                   POST http://localhost:60483/Applicant/Create 500 (Internal Server Error)
d.support.ajax.d.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
d.extend.ajaxjquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
d.each.d.(anonymous function)jquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
$.dialog.buttons.SavechooseApplicant.js:12
(anonymous function)jquery-ui-1.8.18.js:6369
d.event.handlejquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
d.event.add.k.handle.mjquery-1.5.1.min.js:19
6event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

Comment: right the error is with data but there is no error from the controller I have                                                 var dbApplicant = db.Applicant.Where(g => g.Applicant_name == applicant.Applicant_name).SingleOrDefault();
                        return Json(new { Appli = dbApplicant, Error = string.Empty });

Comment: Two things. First: `500 (Internal Server Error)` means that there is problem with the server (it cannot handle your POST). Second: `event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit` it might be a bug in old jQuery. Upgrade jQuery to the latest (1.7.1).

Comment: I have no more the Internal Server Error but still have problem with the data

Comment: for the alert message it shows [object Object]

Comment: Allright, so now we are sure it enters the callback. Try your code now. Also use `console.log(data);` and see the console to check what exactly comes back from the server (CTRL+SHIFT+J under Chrome).

Comment: Sorry I don't know how I saw that there was no internal server error,coz still appear,Is it a problem with .Dialog or else?

Comment: I made another test, beside returning a structured data I sent just a string and it works!! is there a special processing to send a structured date?

Comment: @Yasminette You have to serialize the data structure prior to sending it to the client, then deserialize it on the client side to consume the data.